# How can I resolve this binomial equation by coding?

Tags: python

I'm having a problem finding out how to discover the write function to solve this problem:

*Write a function that will take as an input **two numbers (l,m)** and return as a **tuple the coefficients (a,b,c)** for the quadratic equation a x^2 + b x + c found **from expanding (x + l) * (x + m)**.*

```
def func(l,m): 
    a = 1 
    equation = (a * (x ** 2)) + (b * x) + c 
    coef = [a,b,c]
    eq2 = (x + m) * (x + l)
    coef1 = m + l
    coef2 = m * l
    if coef1 == coef[1] and coef2 == coef[2]: 
        return coef  
func(2,2)
```

Comment: Your problem is probably with the math behind this not the coding. If it is behind the coding you should consider following a simple course on python, how to create functions and do basic operations.

Comment: i dont think its the math...cause i know that b = m + l and c = m* l... but when i try to write the function, i cant assign any value to X without giving him a quantatitve value like 1

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: def func(l,m):
    a = 1
    equation = (a * (x ** 2)) + (b * x) + c
    coef = [a,b,c]
    eq2 = (x + m) * (x + l)
    
    coef1 = m + l
    coef2 = m * l
    if coef1 == coef[1] and coef2 == coef[2]:
        return coef
func(2,2)

Comment: You might want to edit your question and add the code there. In the comments it's unreadable.

Comment: I just have to say that it's pretty funny to see `Jao` and `Joao` having a conversation ^_^

Comment: I proposed an edit for your post, please accept it if it is correct.

Comment: So, i dont want to assign any value to x and a...but im always having the error on those two

Comment: I'm not sure i understand the problem. According to your problem statement, `a` will always be `1`, and as you said yourself - `b = l + m` and `c = l * m`. So with what are you having difficulties?

Comment: a should be another coefficient that the function should find by itself(not assigning the value 1 to a manually). The other problem is x should be a variable like in math

Comment: What do you mean? Your assignment says: *coefficients (a,b,c) for the quadratic equation a x^2 + b x + c found from expanding (x + l) * (x + m)*. By expanding that you get `x^2 + (l+m)*x + l*m` which means that `a = 1 ; b = l + m ; c = l*m`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make it clear:

Your problem states:

> return as a tuple the coefficients `(a,b,c)` for the quadratic equation
> `a x^2 + b x + c` **found from expanding `(x + l) * (x + m)`**.

Let's find the equation by expanding:

```
  (x + l) * (x + m) =
= x^2 + l*x + m*x + l*m =
= x^2 + (l+m)*x + l*m
```

Now, by coefficients comparison with `a x^2 + b x + c`, we get that:

```
a = 1
b = l + m
c = l * m
```

So your function can basically `return (1, l + m, l * m)` directly...

Comment: yes but that is by doing it manually... but if i do that, im assuming that only me know both equations...i will just write the solution... not the actual function to solve the problem

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what's bothering you... This is working with what you get which is `l` and `m`. By only knowing `l` and `m` we can deduct `a, b, c`

Comment: forget about this hahah! my bad...i was assuming the variable a was in the problem( like (a* x +m)(a*x +l) so it could be more generalize...my bad guys! sorry

Answer (score 0):

Now that we have your code, I can tell you you're not using Python functions right. You can't create an unknown variable as you can do in math (here you called `x`)

There are modules who allow such operation with different syntax such as [SymPy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html).

If you don't want to use it and you want to solve it "by-hand" maybe for a school project you'll need to compute `a`, `b` and `c`only from `l` and `m` with formulas.

As mentionned Tomerikoo

```
a = 1
b = l + m
c = l * m
```

Comment: But there's nothing really to compute with outside libraries... OP already said in a comment that it's simply `b = l+m` and `c = l*m`...

Comment: Yep I was going to add that to my answer. 
I wanted to provide OP with a "framework" for such problem solving they provided. I agree with you this particular problem is just these two operations.

Comment: Yap...i know i could solve this by using modules but it need to be "by-hand".

Comment: Follow @Tomerikoo's help and replace the content of your function with the code provided above.

Comment: I'll try ur suggestion, thank you! I thought it would be another way

Comment: what should i assign to x then?

Comment: You don't need x in this problem, see they only ask for a, b and c. Because you want to define the function. x is the variable like in f(x) = ax^2+bx+c